# Why does the property of a projectile is different from a parabola (with the opening downward) represented by a quadratic equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, coordinate-systems, projectile

The property of a projectile make me think about those sine and cosine graphs I had learned in trigonometry class, which the distance between every two points on that parabola is the same but the intervals between the points are getting bigger and bigger in the $y$-axis. (I just thought this is interesting)

In the case of a projectile, the object's vertical trajectory ($y$) is independent of what's happening horizontally ($x$). But I have this question, we know that a quadratic equation can also present as a parabola with the opening downward, such as $y=x^2-5x+3$, and here, the value of $y$ is depend on $x$, so why does the relationship between $y$ and $x$ is different in these two cases? I think since they are all parabola, their properties should be the same , at least similar to each other instead of being completely the opposite.

Comment: Wait, what? sine and cosine are not parabolas - only at the 'hump' are they similar. (Joke: I also like that this question is most similar to "Gravity with different equivalence principles". See "Related" on right)

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. Actually, my main point of this question is to show my amazement of how physic and math are related but somehow is also very different from each other. I know there is a flaw in my first paragraph but that was really the first thought came up my mind.

Comment: But $y=x^2-5x+3$ is a parabola with the opening upwards.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it now. A rotating point as well as projectile motion are 2d motions. Directions x and y can be considered *independently*. There is however a dependence/relation between the two. (mathematically via $t$)

Comment: I thought I had already added a minus symbol before "x^2" , probably my brain was a little dizzy when typing this question

Comment: @ DoctorNuu, can you explain it with a little more details? I want to know what you just got. Please,

Answer (score 3):

In the case of a projectile [with the usual orientation of axes], 
we have the kinematic equations:
$$\begin{align*}
y &=y_0+v_{0,y}t+\frac{1}{2}(-g)t^2\\
x &=x_0+v_{0,x}t
\end{align*}
$$
Here, 
the motion in the $x$- direction **as a function of time**
is independent of 
the motion in the $y$- direction **as a function of time**.
These might be plotted on $x$-vs-$t$ and $y$-vs-$t$ graphs.

However, by eliminating the $t$ parameter, we now have 
$$\begin{align*}
y &=y_0+v_{0,y}\left(\frac{x-x_0}{v_{0,x}}\right)+\frac{1}{2}(-g)\left(\frac{x-x_0}{v_{0,x}}\right)^2
\end{align*}
$$
which describes the trajectory in space as $y$ as **a function of horizontal position** $x$,
which could be plotted on a $y$-vs-$x$ graph.

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all clear what the question is.

Is this it?

If you fire a projectile upward at an angle, it will follow a parabolic path. It will go up and then down.

If you fire the same projectile downward at an angle, it will not go up and then down. It will only go down until it crashes. Why is the motion different?

My answer to that is that you are using the same formula, but starting at the same point you are going opposite directions.